# How do i fix " Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys "?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, nsdictionary

I am trying to sent my parameter through alamofire and in my parameters, there is a duplicate key. I need that key to be passed but whenever i try it , the error pops up.

```
let param : [String: Any] = ["contactPerson": [ "email":[ "email": contactemail], "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,"preferred": false,"shareMarketInd": false], "personName": ["givenName": contactname,"shareMarketInd": false,"surname": contactlastname],"phoneNumber":["countryCode": contactcountrycode,"markedForSendingRezInfo": false,"preferred": false,"shareMarketInd": false,"subscriberNumber": contactphone],"shareMarketInd": false,"useForInvoicing": false,"curr":"USD","flight1" : selectedflightjson,"flight1" : selectedflightjsonRM,"passengers":[passengerparameterarray],"pwd": password,"requestPurpose": "MODIFY_PERMANENTLY_AND_CALC","unm": username
        ]
```

This is my code and "email" : ["email".. comes twice. How do i fix it? i went to few questions in StackOverflow but they all talk about getting this kind of response from server. But here i am trying to sent it to the server.

So how do i fix this?

```
{
    "contactPerson": {
        "email": {
            "email": "a@gmail.com",
            "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
            "preferred": false,
            "shareMarketInd": false
        },
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "v",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "j"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
            "countryCode": "1",
            "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
            "preferred": false,
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "subscriberNumber": "123456789"
        },
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "useForInvoicing": false
    },
```

This is a part of my json.  Also [passengerparameterarray] has the same issue, will it work if i covert  [passengerparameterarray] into a json and pass it to this parameters? Im already passing 'selectedflightjson' as a Json, since this is a soap api.

Thanks.

Comment: `"email" : ["email"` is nested in another dictionary. That is not the problem. You have `"flight1"` key twice. `"flight1" : selectedflightjson,"flight1" : selectedflightjsonRM`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR oh sorry for the stupid question. I did not see that. Sorry for wasting you time. Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage your object as follows:

```
    let param : [String: Any] =
        [
            "contactPerson": [
                "email": [
                    "email": contactemail,
                    "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
                    "preferred": false,
                    "shareMarketInd": false
                ],
            "personName": [
                "givenName": contactname,
                "shareMarketInd": false,
                "surname": contactlastname
            ],
            "phoneNumber": [
                "countryCode": contactcountrycode,
                "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
                "preferred": false,
                "shareMarketInd": false,
                "subscriberNumber": contactphone
            ],
            "passengers": [
                passengerparameterarray
            ],
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "useForInvoicing": false,
            "curr": "USD",
            "flight1": selectedflightjson,
            "flight2": selectedflightjsonRM,
            "pwd": password,
            "requestPurpose": "MODIFY_PERMANENTLY_AND_CALC",
            "unm": username
    ]
```